# How to save a 3D scene by using Scenekit in iOS?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I need to build a 3d editor in iOS. It should load 3d models to a scene and move, rotata, scale, add and remove 3d nodes. But I don't know whether I can export the 3d scene to a file (not just .scn) that other 3d tools like maya and 3d max can use it. If scenekit doesn't work, is there any solutions I can use to solve my problem?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest method to export a SceneKit scene as a Collada .dae file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555325/easiest-method-to-export-a-scenekit-scene-as-a-collada-dae-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the documentation : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene/1523577-write
I would say this is not possible from an iOS device to export in a different format than .scn

Comment: thanks, do you know an other way around to do it in ios?

Comment: There is no other way for the moment apparently. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555325/easiest-method-to-export-a-scenekit-scene-as-a-collada-dae-file and comments.

Comment: You can accept my answer if you think it's correct ;)

Comment: This answer's only correct if you, for some reason, can't use Model I/O in your project. It's a native framework that can be used to export scenes to multiple supported formats, has very easy-to-use interoperability with SceneKit, and is available on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

This is not for a full .scn but it may gives you some ideas on how to do it.

It is in Chinese but Google Translate does a good job at translating it.

https://mur.elii.io/iphone-x-face-tracking-capture-houdini/

He is saving the data 2 ways . One as a .txt file in the App Documents folder or sending it directly into Houdini in real time. You can transfer the .txt file to your Mac using iTunes (File Sharing)

There is another video on YouTube where they send the data to Blender

Elisha Hung XCode Face Capture X source code:
https://github.com/elishahung/FaceCaptureX