# How to export the contents of a SceneKit scene under MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, scenekit, collada

I'm getting unexpected results when exporting the contents of a SceneKit scene to a Collada (.dae) file. Here's what I have so far.

I created a simple scene with 5 spheres along the x-axis

```
var x:CGFloat = 0
for i in 0...4 {
    let sphere = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 1))
    sphere.name = "sphere\(i+1)"
    sphere.position = SCNVector3(x: x, y: 0, z: 0)
    exportScene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere)
    x += 2
}
```

and exported the contents with

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathName)
exportScene.write(to: url, options: nil, delegate: nil) { totalProgress, error, stop in
    print("Export progress: \(totalProgress * 100.0)%")
}
```

When I load the .dae file into a 3D program (Cheetah 3D), I expect to have 5 identical spheres along the x-axis but instead the following appears. I had similar issues exporting to a .obj file.

[image]

The answer in the following says "Keep in mind that DAE doesn't handle all features of SceneKit, though" but the doesn't go into the limitations of the file format.

[Easiest method to export a SceneKit scene as a Collada .dae file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555325/easiest-method-to-export-a-scenekit-scene-as-a-collada-dae-file)

Q: Does anyone know how to export the contents of a SceneKit scene?

Comment: Can you share the project for download? I'd like to have a look at it, if you allow me.

Comment: @ZAY Steps to test the above: 1) create a new SceneKit project, 2) In GameViewController's viewDidLoad function, define `let exportScene = SCNScene()` and then copy/paste the code above, 3) Compile and run

Comment: what did you use as the "pathName" variable? can you qive me a quick example?

Comment: @ZAY pathName is the output path name. It needs to have a .dae extension. Example, `let pathName = "/Users/\(NSUserName())/Desktop/test.dae"`

Comment: Please share the .dae file so we can analyse it in the text editor.

Comment: Well, the Problem seems to be really bad. I made a tests using an iPhone and your code. On the iPhone that compiles and displays 5 SCNSpheres side by side. Then, when I save this (found a solution) this happens: MacOS File preview does not show anything (white on white). Then copied it to PC: Blender 3, open the Collada, Blender Crash. Then tested it using Photoshop. Can open file, I see one (ugly shaped) black Sphere. Just one, not five. Then I did an export using Model/IO, the result: One Shere exported with 5 Materials. Sorry, currently I have no solution for you.

Comment: @de The .dae file can't be loaded into a text editor because it contains some binary data

Comment: @ZAY I'm convinced it's a bug

Comment: dae is an xml format - afaik there is no binary version!?

Answer (score 1):

### macOS app

Looks like the beginning of SceneKit's sunset.

Neither `.dae` nor `.obj` formats are properly generated in SceneKit macOS app. Moreover, an `.usdz` format is not exported at all.

### iOS app

In iOS app, only the `.usdz` format is exported correctly (it kept all nodes' transforms and names of the SCN scene). This `.usdz` can be opened in Maya. But `.dae` and `.obj` files contain only one sphere instead of five.

If you have problems with USDZ's textures in Maya, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72992957/usdz-conversions-using-maya-and-adding-animations/73021270#73021270) please.

[image]

Note that `.usdz` is not exported correctly when using `for-in` loop.

```
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView
        sceneView.backgroundColor = .black
        sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
        let url = URL(string: "file:///Users/swift/Desktop/model.usdz")!

        let sphere1 = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 0.5))
        sphere1.position = SCNVector3(x: -2, y: 0, z: 0)
        sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere1)
        
        // ...sphere2, sphere3, sphere4...
        
        let sphere5 = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 0.5))
        sphere5.position = SCNVector3(x: 2, y: 0, z: 0)
        sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere5)
            
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            sceneView.scene?.write(to: url, delegate: nil) { (prgs, _, _) in
                print("Export progress: \(prgs * 100.0)%")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P. S.

***Tested it on macOS 13.0 Ventura, Xcode 14.1, iOS 16.1 Simulator***.

Comment: Surely this must have previously worked, or at least worked better, in earlier versions of iOS? Otherwise there would be mention of it on SO prior to July 2022, and I don't think there is. Currently completely stymied exporting from SceneKit to anything other than USD(Z), any ideas?

Comment: Just tested. Works fine with `.usdz`, `.dae` and `.scn` export.

Comment: Thanks for checking. SCN and USDZ work, DAE is still affected by the problem you’ve documented here; perhaps your scene wasn’t quite complex enough to trigger it.

Comment: I’m testing on 16.1, are you on 16.2?

Comment: 16.1 (I wrote that at the end of my post). I haven't tried opening `.dae` in Maya, but from Xcode the file generated visually fine.

Comment: Yes I saw that in your post, but the post says .dae only got you one sphere, which is exactly my experience.