# USDZ conversions using Maya and adding animations

Tags: scenekit, arkit, maya, realitykit, reality-composer

I am really new to AR development so forgive me for my obvious questions. I am trying to make a simple AR app where I have used some image anchors to place 3D models of an iPhone in my scene. I don't have experience working with 3D models so I downloaded a few USDZ files from SketchFab.

For my use case I need to add animations on the 3D models iPhone's screen.

Referring to this : [How to create a .usdz animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009105/how-to-create-a-usdz-animation)

I tried to download Maya and work on it, but every time I import a usdz to Maya, it looses it's texture. I tried the Apple `.usdz` models too, and tried to use the steps mentioned in the question mentioned above, but I always lost the textures. I have gone over so many Maya tutorials and documentation to know what I might be missing but nothing seems to be working. If someone could please help me with this import to maya and then convert using the Reality Converter, that's be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To "retain" USDZ model's textures in Maya, use unzipped ascii USDA or binary USDC files instead.

Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55544185/how-to-generate-usdz-file-again-from-zip-file/55631922#55631922) to find out how to unzip and rezip USDZ model.

[image: This screenshot shows how Apple's teapot.usdz looks like in Maya.]

This screenshot shows how Apple's `teapot.usdc` looks like in Maya.